# jquery autocomplete not working with codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

first of all, yes I know there are other questions similar to this already and I've tried the solutions there but no luck.

I'm using PHP, codeigniter and jquery UI autocomplete. I'm following [this](http://www.codersmount.com/2012/09/jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-codeigniter-with-database/) tutorial and it doesn't work.

My model:

```
class Tags_model extends Model{
  function get_tag($q){   
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","km_portal") or die("Could not connect");
    $query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM resource WHERE tags LIKE '%".$q."%'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){           
            $new_row['label']= $row['tags'];
            $new_row['value']= $row['tags'];
            $row_set[] = $new_row; //build an array
        }
       echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json       
    }}}
```

My view:

```
<?php echo form_open('search/do_search');?>
    <input type="text" name="search" id="tags" placeholder="Search tags"/>
    <input type="submit" value=">>" />
    <span id="noMatches"></span>
</form>
```

with the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: "search/get_tags",
        response: function(event,ui){
            if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                $("#noMatches").html("No matches");
            } else {
                $("#noMatches").empty();
            }
        }
    });
}));
```

And then lastly, my controller:

```
function get_tags(){
   $this->load->model('tags_model');

    if(isset($_GET['term'])){
        $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
        $this->tags_model->get_tag($q);
    }}
```

Checking the Chrome console when I try to run this, the error seems to be that the parameter 'term' appends itself to the url making it: `localhost/km/index.php/search/get_tags?term=a`. I get the error 404 (Not Found)

Any help would truly be appreciated. I've been stuck with this for over a month (This is the first time i'm using codeigniter by the way).

Thanks!

EDIT: using the following js:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom\jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom\external\jquery\jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom\jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you added `jquery.ui.js`?

Comment: Hello, yes I've linked to it already. Thanks for reminding me to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a routing problem I'm guessing your url for search is

http://domain.com/search/get_tags?term=blah

I see the problem here:

```
<?php echo form_open('search/do_search');?>
    <input type="text" name="search" id="tags" placeholder="Search tags"/>
    <input type="submit" value=">>" />
    <span id="noMatches"></span>
</form>
```

The path to the form should be like this: `/search/do_search`

To make an absolute path otherwise you are getting the relative path

EDIT: Just for helping you, when I have used autocomplete I used to check in google if the url, in your case `http://domain.com/search/get_tags?term=blah`, is retrieving well the json correctly, to debug problems

Comment: hello! thanks for the suggestion, but i've done this and it didnt change anything. still can't get the autocomplete to work :(

Comment: Can you show me what message of error are you getting in the browser-console?